# Wiener isometry for semimartingales

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, hilbert-spaces, martingales

Suppose that $Y_t$ is a special square-integrable $\mathbb{R}$-valued semi-martingale and let $\mathcal{L}^2(Y)$ denote the set of $Y$-predictable processes satisfying
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[
\int_0^{\infty} f_s^2 d[Y]_s 
\right]<\infty
.
$$

Wiener's isometry says that, when $Y$ is a Brownian motion, then the map
$$
\begin{aligned}
&L^2[0,1]\rightarrow \mathcal{L}^2(Y)\\
&\phi_s\mapsto \int_0^t \phi_s dY_s,
\end{aligned}
$$
is a (Hilbert) isometry.  Is this true for $Y$ as above?

Comment: Yes it's true, and the proof should be exactly the same as for Brownian motion: prove it for step functions $\phi$ by direct calculation, and then note that such functions are dense in $L^2([0,1])$.  More generally, the Ito isometry also holds; see https://almostsure.wordpress.com/2010/03/29/quadratic-variations-and-the-ito-isometry/.

Comment: Nice, that's what I expected.  Thanks for the link Nate:)

Comment: How about if you write your own answer, filling in the details?

Comment: So there are isometries between $L^2([0,1]),\mathcal{L}^2(Y)$ where $Y$ is a *semi-*martingale?  But this is not covered by Ito...which only deals with local martingales and is an isometry with $\mathcal{H}_0^2$ (the second Martingale-Hardy space).  (Unless I am mistaken)